# Knp Paginator Bundle route error when using slug

Tags: symfony, pagination, knppaginator, knppaginatorbundle

I'd like to implement the Knp Pagination for a table.

It is a page where I edit documents, so my route looks like that:
@Route("/document/edit/{id}/") and depending on the document, there is a different ID. 
There are several panels on the page and one of them contains a table of different agencies. For that table I used the knp_paginator:

```
/**
    * @var $paginator \Knp\Component\Pager\Paginator
    */
    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $agencyTable = $paginator->paginate(
      $docAgencies,
      $request->query->getId('page', 1),
      5
    );
```

the $docAgencies is defined like that so it's no query, but that's the way I need to get the information!

```
  $document = $em->getRepository('DocumentBundle:Document')->findOneByIdInContext($id, $currentuser);
      $docAgencies = $document->getAgencies();
```

When first accessing the page, everything is fine and page one of the table is being shown, but as soon as I try to click on another page of the table I get an error:

```
Controller "DocumentBundle\Controller\Document\EditController::editAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$id" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).
```

and my route looks like this:

```
http://localhost/sp/web/app_dev.php/document/document/edit?page=3
```

so the id of the document was just deleted and there's nothing to be accessed.
I tried to add a /{page} to my route like it was recommended in other Stackoverflow questions but this doesn't seem to work for me either.
That's how I tried it:

```
  * @Route("/document/edit/{id}/{pag}", name="documentBundle_edit", requirements={"id" = "\d+", "pag" = "\d+"}, defaults={"id" = 0, "pag":1})
```

the editAction:

```
    public function editAction(Request $request, $id, $pag) {
..
```

and within the paginate function:

```
  $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $agencyTable = $paginator->paginate(
      $docAgencies,
      $pag,
      5
    );
```

any ideas why this is not working?

**update** twig view

```
    {% block content %}

{{ form_start(form) }}

<div class="row">
{% include 'Form/form_errors_banner.html.twig' %}
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <legend>{{ 'header.info'|trans }}</legend>
      {% include 'DocumentBundle:Panels:DocumentInfo.html.twig' %}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <legend>{{ 'label.comments'|trans }}</legend>
      {% include 'AppBundle::CommentTable.html.twig' with {
      'entity': document,
      'add_comments': true
      } %}
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">

      <legend>{{ 'label.distribution'|trans }}</legend>


<div id="upload_profile_no">
{% trans_default_domain 'AppBundle' %}

{# CONFIG #}
{% if deleteButton is not defined %}
    {% set deleteButton = true %}
{% endif %}
    {{ form_label(form.agencies) }}<br>
    {{ form_widget(form.agencies) }} <br> <br>
    <table class="footable">
        {# header fields #}
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="iata">{{ 'label.iata'|trans }}</th>
                <th data-field="name">{{ 'label.name'|trans }}</th>
                <th data-field="city">{{ 'label.city'|trans }}</th>
                <th data-field="country">{{ 'label.country'|trans }}</th>
                {% if deleteButton %}<th data-field="delete"></th>{% endif %}
            </tr>
        </thead>

      {% block tablebody %}
        {# body fields #}
        <tbody>
            {% for agency in docAgencies %}
                <tr>
                    <td data-title="iata" data-market="{{ agency.market.id }}"><a href="{{ path('appBundle_agencyEdit', {'id': agency.id}) }}">{{ agency.id }}</a></td>
                    <td data-title="name">{{ agency.account }}</td>
                    <td data-title="city">{{ agency.cityName }}</td>
                    <td data-title="country">{{ agency.market.id }}</td>
                    {% if deleteButton %}
                        <td data-title="delete">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-remove-row" type="button" data-index="{{ agency.id }}">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
                            </button>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-undo-remove hidden" type="button" data-index="{{ agency.id }}">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></span>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    {% endif %}
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    {% endblock %}
    </table>
    {% if docAgencies.pageCount > 1 %}
    <div class="navigation text-center">
        {{ knp_pagination_render(docAgencies) }}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>

  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      {{ form_row(form.airlines, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-inline'} }) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      {{ form_row(form.products, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-inline'} }) }}
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <legend>{{ 'label.attachments'|trans }}</legend>
    {% set fileDomain = 'document' %}
    {% include 'AppBundle::AttachmentConfig.html.twig' %}
    {% include 'AppBundle::DisplayAttachments.html.twig' with {'entity': document} %}
    {% include 'AppBundle::FileUpload.html.twig' %}
  </div>
</div>


</div>

</div>


<div class="row">
  {% include 'AppBundle::HelpSubmitButton.html.twig' %}
</div>
  {{ form_end(form) }}
  {% include 'DocumentBundle:Action/UploadProfile:modals.html.twig' %}

{% endblock content %}
```

the part for the pagination is the table with `{% for agency in docAgencies %}`

**update 2 **
my full controller:

```
class EditController extends Controller {


   /**
    * @Route("/document/edit", name="documentBundle_edit2")
    * @Route("/document/edit/{id}/{pag}", name="documentBundle_edit", requirements={"id" = "\d+", "pag" = "\d+"}, defaults={"id" = 0, "pag" = 1})
    * @Template()
    */

    public function editAction(Request $request, $id, $pag) {

      $currentuser = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $document = $em->getRepository('DocumentBundle:Document')->findOneByIdInContext($id, $currentuser);
      $allComments = $document->getComments();
      $docAgencies = $document->getAgencies();
      $statusRepository = $em->getRepository('DocumentBundle:Status');

      if($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_DOCUMENT_EDIT') && $document->getStatus()->getName() == 'Effective' && $document->isActive()
      || $this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_CONTRACT_ADMIN')){

        /*
        * GET DOCUMENT FROM DB
        */

        /*
        * CHECK Document
        */
        if($document == null)
        {
          return $this->get('app.error_helper')->throwError('error.404');
        }

        $form = $this->createForm(DocumentEditType::class, $document);

        /*
        * CREATE PAGINATION FOR TABLES
        */
        /**
        * @var $paginator \Knp\Component\Pager\Paginator
        */
        $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
        $agencyTable = $paginator->paginate(
          $docAgencies,
          $pag,
          5
        );
        $agencyTable->setTemplate('DocumentBundle::table_pagination.html.twig');
        $agencyTable->setUsedRoute('documentBundle_edit');
        $agencyTable->setParam('id', $id);
        $commentTable = $paginator->paginate(
          $allComments,
          $pag,
          5
        );
        $commentTable->setTemplate('DocumentBundle::table_pagination.html.twig');

        /*
        * IF REQUEST IS VALID
        */
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {

        $effective = date_format($document->getEffective(), 'Y-m-d');
        $expires = date_format($document->getExpires(), 'Y-m-d');
        $now = date('Y-m-d');

        if($now < $effective) {
            $status = $statusRepository->findOneById('3');
        } elseif ($now >= $expires) {
            $status = $statusRepository->findOneById('2');
        } else {
            $status = $statusRepository->findOneById('1');
        }

        $document->setStatus($status);
          $em->flush();
          $this->addFlash(
          'success',
          'The document has been edited!'
          );
          return $this->redirectToRoute('documentBundle_document_list');
        }
        /*
        * DISPLAY Document
        */
        return $this->render('DocumentBundle:Document:edit.html.twig', Array(
          'document' => $document,
          'docAgencies' => $agencyTable,
          'comments' => $commentTable,
          'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
      } else {
        /*
        * THROW ERROR
        * If the acting user is not allowed to perform this action
        */
        return $this->redirectToRoute('documentBundle_view_document', array(
          'id' => $id
      ));

    }
    }
}
```

**table_pagination.html.twig**

```
<nav>
<ul class="pagination">
  {# Previous #}
  {% if startPage == 1 %}
    <li class="disabled">
      <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  {% else %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), {'page': startPage - 1}) }} " aria-label="Previous">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  {% endif %}
    {# Pages #}
  {% if pageCount < 12 %}{# less than 12 Pages #}
    {% for i in 1..pageCount %}
        <li {% if startPage == i %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), {'page': i}) }} ">{{i}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
      {% if startPage < 8 %}{# any current page before 7 #}
      {# Pages #}
      {% for i in 1..8 %}
          <li {% if startPage == i %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), {'page': i}) }} ">{{i}}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
      <li class="disabled"><a href="#">...</a></li>
      <li><a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), {'page': pageCount - 1}) }} ">{{pageCount - 1}}</a></li>
      <li><a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), {'page': pageCount}) }} ">{{pageCount}}</a></li>
      {% else %}
        {% if startPage > pageCount - 7 %}{# any current page in the last 7 #}
          {# Pages #}
          <li><a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), {'page': 1}) }} ">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), {'page': 2}) }} ">2</a></li>
          <li class="disabled"><a href="#">...</a></li>
          {% for i in 7..0 %}
              <li {% if startPage == pageCount - i %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), {'page': pageCount - i}) }} ">{{pageCount - i}}</a></li>
          {% endfor %}
          {% else %}{# any other Page #}
            <li><a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), {'page': 1}) }} ">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), {'page': 2}) }} ">2</a></li>
            <li class="disabled"><a href="#">...</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), {'page': startPage - 2}) }} ">{{startPage - 2}}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), {'page': startPage - 1}) }} ">{{startPage - 1}}</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), {'page': startPage}) }} ">{{startPage}}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), {'page': startPage + 1}) }} ">{{startPage + 1}}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), {'page': startPage + 2}) }} ">{{startPage + 2}}</a></li>
            <li class="disabled"><a href="#">...</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), {'page': pageCount - 1}) }} ">{{pageCount - 1}}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), {'page': pageCount}) }} ">{{pageCount}}</a></li>
          {% endif %}{# any current page in the last 7 #}
        {% endif %}{# any current page before 8 #}
      {% endif %}{# less than 12 Pages #}
  {# Next #}
  {% if startPage == pageCount %}
    <li class="disabled">
      <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  {% else %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), {'page': startPage + 1}) }} " aria-label="Next">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  {% endif %}
</ul>
</nav>
```

**update including @ste 's help **
Edit Controller:

```
 * @Route("/document/edit/{id}/{page}", name="documentBundle_edit", requirements={"id" = "\d+", "page" = "\d+"}, defaults={"page" = 1})
        * @Template()
        */

        public function editAction(Request $request, $id, $page) {
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $document = $em->getRepository('DocumentBundle:Document')->findOneByIdInContext($id, $currentuser);
      $allComments = $document->getComments();
      $docAgencies = $document->getAgencies();
    /*
        * CREATE PAGINATION FOR TABLES
        */
        /**
        * @var $paginator \Knp\Component\Pager\Paginator
        */
        $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
        $agencyTable = $paginator->paginate(
          $docAgencies,
          $page,
          5
        );
        $agencyTable->setTemplate('DocumentBundle::table_pagination.html.twig');
        $commentTable = $paginator->paginate(
          $allComments,
          $page,
          5
        );
        $commentTable->setTemplate('DocumentBundle::table_pagination.html.twig');
  return $this->render('DocumentBundle:Document:edit.html.twig', Array(
          'document' => $document,
          'docAgencies' => $agencyTable,
          'comments' => $commentTable,
          'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
}
```

the pagination template

```
{# Pagination to be included anywhere. Needs {page, pageCount} #}
<nav>
<ul class="pagination">
  {# Previous #}
  {% if startPage == 1 %}
    <li class="disabled">
      <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  {% else %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({'page': startPage - 1})) }} " aria-label="Previous">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  {% endif %}
    {# Pages #}
  {% if pageCount < 12 %}{# less than 12 Pages #}
    {% for i in 1..pageCount %}
        <li {% if startPage == i %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({'page': i})) }} ">{{i}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
      {% if startPage < 8 %}{# any current page before 7 #}
      {# Pages #}
      {% for i in 1..8 %}
          <li {% if startPage == i %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({'page': i})) }}">{{i}}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
      <li class="disabled"><a href="#">...</a></li>
      <li><a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({'page': pageCount - 1})) }}">{{pageCount - 1}}</a></li>
      <li><a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({'page': pageCount})) }}">{{pageCount}}</a></li>
      {% else %}
        {% if startPage > pageCount - 7 %}{# any current page in the last 7 #}
          {# Pages #}
          <li><a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({'page': 1})) }} ">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({'page': 2})) }} ">2</a></li>
          <li class="disabled"><a href="#">...</a></li>
          {% for i in 7..0 %}
              <li {% if startPage == pageCount - i %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({'page': pageCount - i})) }} ">{{pageCount - i}}</a></li>
          {% endfor %}
          {% else %}{# any other Page #}
            <li><a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({'page': 1})) }}">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({'page': 2})) }}">2</a></li>
            <li class="disabled"><a href="#">...</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({'page': startPage - 2})) }} ">{{startPage - 2}}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({'page': startPage - 1})) }} ">{{startPage - 1}}</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({'page': startPage})) }} ">{{startPage}}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({'page': startPage + 1})) }}">{{startPage + 1}}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({'page': startPage + 2})) }} ">{{startPage + 2}}</a></li>
            <li class="disabled"><a href="#">...</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({'page': pageCount - 1})) }} ">{{pageCount - 1}}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({'page': pageCount})) }} ">{{pageCount}}</a></li>
          {% endif %}{# any current page in the last 7 #}
        {% endif %}{# any current page before 8 #}
      {% endif %}{# less than 12 Pages #}
  {# Next #}
  {% if startPage == pageCount %}
    <li class="disabled">
      <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  {% else %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({'page': startPage + 1})) }} " aria-label="Next">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  {% endif %}
</ul>
</nav>
```

and this is how I add the pagination to my template:

```
{{ knp_pagination_render(docAgencies) }}
```

Comment: Please post you twig view

Comment: I added it to my post @ste :)

Comment: Mmmh could you post the full controller?

Comment: do you have an entry in config.yml under `knp_paginator` - `template` - `pagination` ? if so, please post the pointed file

Comment: @ste I added the controller & in my config.yml the default template is set: @KnpPaginator/Pagination/foundation_v5_pagination.html.twig but I then set the table_pagination.html.twig file in my controller as a template, which I added to my question as well :)

Comment: hey @ste I'm still kind of stuck here and you are my only hope right now. do you have any further ideas? :)

Comment: Why do you have two paginators (one for allComments and one for docAgencies)  with the same variable containing the page number?

Comment: oh would they need their own page variable?
But I guess that doesn't help my content problem, right?

Comment: so I tried it with just one table using the "page" variable. but the content still doesn't change :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have a problem in `table_pagination.html.twig`.

You should replace this:

```
{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), {'page': THE_PAGE_YOU_HAVE}) }}
```

with this:

```
{{ path(route, query|merge({'pag': THE_PAGE_YOU_HAVE})) }}
```

or this

```
{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.query.all|merge({'pag': THE_PAGE_YOU_HAVE})) }}
```

Let me know if it works.

Further, you should remove the default value for `id` in your route for `editAction`

Comment: Hi @ste thanks for your answer. I think I'm almost there now! Switching pages is working route wise, the document ID remains! But what's not working is that the content actually changes. When trying to get the content of page 2 of my table, the route changes to page=2 but the content stays the same as on page one..

Comment: @sonja did you use the first or the second solution?

Comment: uhm sure, you used a differente variable name (`pag` instead of `page`). I updated the answer.

Comment: I am using the first one. I also tried the second but with that one I got the same error message as with my own code. :)

Comment: Oh right, how stupid of me, I'm sorry!
Ok I hope now this is my last question: I removed the default value for the ID as you suggested but this exception "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Some mandatory parameters are missing ("id") to generate a URL for route "documentBundle_edit".")." is shown now, even though the route is correct "http://localhost/sp/web/app_dev.php/document/document/edit/42". That's weird, right?

Comment: oh ok, that was the case with your second solution. the first one doesn't throw that exception but with the first one my first incident (content not changing) remains.. :)

Comment: @sonja did you update `page` with `pag` in the template as described in the updated answer?

Comment: yes I did! I actually just changed pag to page in my controller. thought that'd make more sense :)

Comment: @sonja if it doesn't work, please post all your updated code in your question (config, controller, templates...), there should be something wrong somewhere

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157066/discussion-between-ste-and-sonja).